# Are the eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian always in $L^2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

In physics (in particular quantum mechanics), an important operator is the [Hamiltonian operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_(quantum_mechanics)). It plays an extremely important role, as it's spectrum gives the possible values for the energy of the system.

Now, in general, the eigenvectors of a self-adjoint operator defined on a dense subspace of an infinite dimensional Hilbert space are not always elements of the said Hilbert space (this spans the theory for rigged Hilbert spaces). However, in all the quantum systems I have encountered so far it seems that the eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian operator are always in the underlying Hilbert space. Is there a reason for this (like some special property that comes from the form of the Hamiltonian/the nice potential terms people generally use) or is it just pure coincidence (and maybe there are systems where this is not true and I just haven't had the chance to encounter them)?

Comment: Have you encountered the free particle in $\mathbb R^3$ ? the corresponding $H$ has no square-integrable eigenstates right ?

Comment: For a wide range of potentials (but not "most" by any means), the single particle Hamiltonian has compact resolvent. In this case the spectral theorem for compact operators gives you that there is a basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: Actually, the possible energies of a QM system are the values in the spectrum of the Hamiltonian. In general, the spectrum contains lots of values which are not eigenvalues. Also, by definition, an operator has a domain, and again by definition, all its eigenvectors are its domain. So to answer your question it would be helpful to know where you want to define you Hamiltonan.

Answer (score 1):

It is logically inconsistent to say that an eigenvector of the Hamiltonian $H$ is not in the space $X$. By definition, an eigenvector is a vector in the vector space $X$ under consideration. You can have approximate eigenvectors in the space. For example, you may well encounter a situation where $\{ \phi_{n} \}\subset X$ satisfies
$$\|(H-\lambda I)\phi_n\| \le \frac{1}{n}\|\phi_n\|,\;\; \phi_n \ne 0,\;\; n=1,2,3,\cdots,$$
even though there may not be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$. This is typical of the continuous spectrum of a self-adjoint operator $H$. The measurement of $H$ for $\phi_n$ is nearly $\lambda$, and the precision with which this is true is increasing with increasing $n$. So the value of $H$ can be made arbitrarily close to $\lambda$, even though it may never actually be $\lambda$.

Comment: By eigenvector not being in the space I had in mind the momentum on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ for example, for which the eigenfunctions $e^{ipx}$ are not square integrable (sure, in this case people often talk about generalized eigenvectors). As others have commented, the same is true for the free particle in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, which I indeed missed.

Comment: $e^{ipx}$ is not $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. However, $\int_{p-\epsilon}^{p+\epsilon}e^{ip'x}dp'$ is in the space, and this is increasingly closer to an eigenvector with eigenvalue $p$ as $\epsilon\downarrow 0$.